# How can I change ng2-smart-table's pager position to the right?

Tags: css, angular, ng2-smart-table

I am using the component ng-smart-table and I am changing its style from my project's css. At this point I managed to give style to almost everything with :host and /deep/ in CSS, but now I am struggling with the pager's position, which I would like to change to the right.

[In this demo, you can see the pager's default position](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/)

And this is what I would like to achieve:
[image]

I have tried applying style to the selector .ng2-smart-pagination, which worked for border and background color, but it didn't work with position, display, align, etc. so maybe I am using the wrong selector, but I don't know for sure.

```
/deep/ .ng2-smart-pagination {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/deep/ .ng2-smart-pagination {
  justify-content: flex-end !important;
}
```

[image]

I added important just in case